# operator "<<" to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I have a class Terminallog which is overloading the << operator. If I do the following

```
Terminallog clog(3);
clog << "stackoverflow.com is cool" << endl;
```

everything works fine. "stackoverflow.com is cool" is printed in a nice colored way to the screen, exactly what Terminallog is supposed to do.

Now I try

```
Terminallog* clog = new Terminallog(3);
clog << "stackoverflow.com is cool" << endl;
```

which gives me a compiler error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘Terminallog*’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
```

I can see that it is problem passing the "<<" operator to a pointer, but how can I get the same behaviour as with the non pointer version? I could simply dereference the pointer, but that would create a local copy of the object (which is no good for performance isn't it?)

Therefore I wonder what is the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance

ftiaronsem

Comment: I do not think that dereferencing the pointer creates a local copy of the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dereferencing a pointer to write

```
*clog << "My message" << endl;
```

does **not** create a copy of the object being pointed at.  In general, pointer dereferences don't make copies, and the only way to make a copy is to either explicitly create one, pass an object into a function by value, or return an object from a function by value.  The above code with the pointer dereference is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: For completeness, dereferencing the pointer creates a reference (semantically).

Answer (score 4):

Actually dereferencing the pointer gives you a reference, not a copy, so you're fine. (Attempting to copy a stream would *and should* fail, anyway; streams are not containers but flows of data.)

```
*clog << "text" << std::endl;
```

You can't write a free ("global") function `operator<<` taking a pointer-to-`TerminalLog` on the left and the other stuff on the right, because the language requires at least one of the operands to `operator<<` to be a class or enum type, and your RHS argument often won't be one.

Comment: You reasoning is wrong. The side of the operand has no significance. What matters that at least one of the operands is a class or enum type. (http://ideone.com/4zhQt)

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing the pointer does not create a copy, it creates a reference. You can just de-ref it and get the correct behaviour, no copying.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `(*clog) << "stackoverflow.com is cool" << endl;`

This does not create a copy of `clog`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Terminallog* clog = new Terminallog(3);
Terminallog& clog_r = *clog;
clog_r << "stackoverflow.com is cool" << endl;
```

Comment: you mean `Terminallog& clog_r = *clog;`